# removeImageForTag() not implemented (React Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm getting this `removeImageForTag()` error

[image]

This is my source code

```
ImageEditor.cropImage(
  this.state.image,
  imageData,
  (successURI) => {
    ImageStore.getBase64ForTag(successURI,
      (base64Data) => {
        console.log(base64Data);
      },
      (failure) => {console.log('failed to load')});
    console.log(successURI);
    ImageStore.removeImageForTag(successURI) <<<
  },
  (error) => { console.log('ERROR: ', error)}
)
```

I guess it's package error but the version number seems ok.

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.48.4

"expo": "^21.0.0",
```

removeImageForTag doc is here : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.39/docs/imagestore.html#removeimagefortag

Comment: I guess everyone is having good time on thanks giving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going crazy with this.. how can `removeImageForTag` not be defined for Android?

Then I realised that in Android, the url (successURI in your example) is a path to the app cache (ex: `file:///data/user/0/com.your.project/cache/ReactNative_cropped_image_-1677432906.jpg`).

You can delete the image using any filesystem library (ex: [rn-fetch-blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/wiki/File-System-Access-API#unlinkpathstringpromise), [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#file-deletion) or [Expo.FileSystem.deleteAsync](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem#expofilesystemdeleteasyncfileuri-options) if using expo)

Answer (score 1):

The `removeImageForTag` method is only available on iOS by default. To add support for Android, you can use the following module: https://github.com/seancunningham/react-native-image-store-ext

Comment: Thank :) That library looks great. Do you know any other module? I'm using Expo, and I can't detach it because I'm using Facebook Authentication, Notification, and many

Comment: I didn't know Android is not supporting its function.

Comment: This is the only one I found.

Comment: oh nooooooooooooooooooo